# std::string used with template, check if empty

Tags: c++

I would like to use a function that takes in a general parameter of type `T`, and within the function check if the variable passed in is `NULL`. I could simply do this with primitive types like this:

```
if (var) doSomething();
```

However, in order to check if it's an `std::string`, I would need to do:

```
if (!var.empty()) doSomething();
```

What would be the best, most general way to check if the parameter being passed in is `NULL`? I would like to use all primitive types and `std::string`. Perhaps I could use `typeid`?

Comment: only pointers can be null. other types (like the rest of the primitives and string objects) cannot be null. this question is fundamentally wrong

Comment: You should only check pointers against `NULL`.  This is one of the reasons `nullptr` was created for as `NULL` compares to numeric types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you'd have better luck researching this topic if you used proper terminology. An empty string is not "`NULL`"; a zero-equivalent integer is also not "`NULL`". The only thing that can be "`NULL`" is a pointer (though we use `nullptr` for those nowadays). So right away we can stop using that term.

There is no general "not set" value for arbitrary types, and therefore no common way to detect such a case. However, you can use a wrapper type that explicitly adds this possibility, such as `boost::optional<T>`:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(boost::optional<T> arg)
{
   if (arg)
      std::cout << arg.get() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    boost::optional<int>   a{123};
    boost::optional<int>   b{boost::none};
    boost::optional<float> c{boost::none};
    boost::optional<float> d{123.456};

    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
    foo(d);

    // Or, pass it directly:
    foo(boost::optional<std::string>{"abc"});
    foo(boost::optional<std::string>{boost::none});
    foo(boost::optional<std::string>{});  // as if boost::none were given
}

// $ g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
// 123
// 123.456
// abc
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c9ba047dcec0d54))

Your only other option would be to accept pointers-to-objects and check for `NULL`ity on the pointer. But that is an abstraction leak, because accepting a pointer indicates an intent other than that of this function; it also creates a bit of a mess with respect to clear ownership semantics.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. And thanks for correcting my terminology; I'm still learning and that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could have generic code without repeating yourself by using a template that compares to a default constructed version of the object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void doSomething(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Doing something with " << t << " \n";
}

void doSomethingElse()
{
    std::cout << "Doing something else\n";
}

template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    if (t!=T{}) doSomething(t); // compare with default constructed object
    else doSomethingElse();
}

int main()
{
    int var1{};
    std::string var2{};

    int var3{3};
    std::string var4{"var4's text"};

    f(var1);
    f(var2);
    f(var3);
    f(var4);
}
```

Produces:

```
Doing something else
Doing something else
Doing something with 3
Doing something with var4's text
```